# How to get coordinates of canvas while translating or scaling using Android

Tags: android, canvas, viewport

I am translating the canvas based on user's touch input. I need to be able to save the position of canvas and perform future operations on top of the translated canvas.For instance,

step1: translate canvas by 10,0

step2: apply translate to the previously translated canvas by 40,0

But when I apply the canvas translate after step1 it redraws from original position. A quick fix would be to keep track of how much I've translated by and then translate by the cumulative value, in this case I would have to translate by 50,0 after the first step.

But how can I save the state when scaling the canvas? Especially when scaling about a pivot point?

Comment: Can you post your code?  Calling `canvas.translate()` a second time should prepend the translation to any existing translation in the current canvas matrix.  In other words, it's already cumulative.

Comment: @krislarson: Thank you! I figured it out using matrix.posttranslate